How to change the SSH server port on Ubuntu?
I have changed the SSH server config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Port 2222

Then I restarted the SSH server service: systemctl restart ssh.service.
However, the SSH server is still running on port 22, because I can still reach it on the default port, and ss -tulpn shows:
> ss -tulpn
Netid    State     Recv-Q    Send-Q    Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port    Process
tcp      LISTEN    0         4096                  *:22                 *:*        users:(("sshd",pid=16720,fd=3),("systemd",pid=1,fd=163))

Note: I'm using a freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04 server.

Is there an ssh.socket service unit (systemctl status ssh.socket)? If so, you will need to modify the socket unit (or reconfigure things to not use socket activation).

Apparently, Ubuntu has been using systemd-sockets for some time now, which makes the port configuration in the SSH server configuration obsolete.
To change the port of the SSH server, the systemd configuration for ssh.socket must be changed or supplemented. The configuration adjustment is made by creating a *.conf file in the directory /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/.

Create conf file to extend the default config:
systemctl edit ssh.socket
      or
vim /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/override.conf
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=2222

The line ListenStream= is required that port 22 is no longer used. Without this line, the SSH server would then be accessible via port 22 (default) and 2222.

Restart the socket:
systemctl restart ssh.socket



That's good to know, but this is really preposterous. And the fact that you must have an empty ListenStream line to disable port 22 is a huge security risk. Who thought this was a good idea ? What other security-sensitive configuration parameters in various services are silently overloaded by systemd ? Systemd haters really have a point here.


Who thought this was a good idea ?

This is a question that comes with every systemd update since inception. It's a moot questions, unfortunately.

It works for me, but I had to reboot the server. Simply doing systemctl restart ssh.socket would not work. PS: I understand now why some sysadmins are flocking to FreeBSD...

PS: It was on an ARM VPS. With AMD VPS it works fine.

It gets even better, before restarting the socket you have to systemctl daemon-reload which executes a "sshd-socket-generator" which creates /run/systemd/generator/ssh.socket.d/addresses.conf with required config, i.e. the empty ListenStream and the one with the desired port
Oh, the joy of systemd...
So to recap:

Change port in sshd config as desired
Reload systemd: systemctl daemon-reload
Restart socket: systemctl restart ssh.socket


In the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS I found here: /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.requires/ssh.socket and needed systemctl daemon-reload

@NabiK.A.Z.s solution works. Simply modify this file and restart ssh using "systemctl restart ssh.socket"

remember to adjust firewall rules as well, eg ufw allow 2222/tcp

Without further ado, the solution is:
Make sure to open multiple terminals connected to your server to prevent yourself from getting locked out.

Uncomment the Port key in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config (not /etc/ssh/ssh_config) and change it to the new port.
Change the port listeners in /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.requires/ssh.socket from the old port (e.g. 22) to the new port and Keep other configurations untouched.
Allow the port in your firewall: sudo ufw allow <port>/tcp
Restart the daemon: sudo systemctl daemon-reload.
Restart ssh:sudo systemctl restart ssh and restart the socket sudo systemctl restart ssh.socket
Verify changes: sudo ss -tlnp | grep ssh (Should show your new port).
Test connection in a new terminal: ssh user@<ip> -p <port>. It should work without errors now!

However, if you encountered errors when starting ssh itself (Just like I did and spent hours trying to figure out why and almost got myself locked out of my server), just try to re-install ssh, follow the above steps again and you will be all set up!

another approach:

nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config, uncomment Port 22 and change it YOUR_PORT_NUMBER
sudo ufw allow YOUR_PORT_NUMBER/tcp
disable systemd from using default socket configuration:
sudo systemctl disable ssh.socket && sudo systemctl stop ssh.socket
sudo systemctl restart ssh
sudo ufw reload

Then you can verify your port being listed in sudo ss -tuln
(note, the above approach might not be a default way on Ubuntu versions above 22).

If above does not work, try:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport YOUR_PORT_NUMBER -j ACCEPT

and then restart ssh
(source)

This is explicitly what does not work on Ubuntu.

No, it doesn't work. If you read the other answer, you'll see why it doesn't work. Ubuntu uses systemd to launch ssh on incoming connections, so by the time sshd reads the configuration file it's too late.

@vidarlo just for the sake of completeness, if you have an access to any test server, try the above steps (edited) and if it does not work, i'll delete my answer
